# annotation processors for project are not saved after changing git branch

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have same annotation processors settings for Default and Project. But after I checkout another git branch setting for project will disappear and default left. It would be great if somebody can help me with this issue.

[image: annotation processors settings]

P.S. Idea version: IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1
Build #IU-171.3780.107, built on March 22, 2017

Comment: **setting for project will disappear and default left**...does the maven module structure between the two branches you are switching from differ?

Comment: Problem exists with both identical pom and nonidentical one

Comment: *both identical pom and nonidentical one*...do you mean any branch you switch to, the settings would change? If that's so, could you update the question with IntelliJ version you are using.

Comment: The functionality works fine for me on the shared version. Could you link to the project and specify the details about the branches you are switching using git?

Comment: It is closed repository. What details about branches should I provide?

Comment: I would have given it a try. Basically, what changes between the two branches? My first question, is there any modular change between these two branches that might impact the way you're looking at it?